# How do I parse a date with the format yyyy-w

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I guess the question could be: Is the format `yyyy-w` supported in swift's date formatter? (where w is the week). I know it's supported in Java's `SimpleDateFormat`. If not then how would one parse a date in said format?

Comment: That's not a date. Is it on Sunday? Monday? What's the standard employed? What week numbering standard is it using? Is `2018-1` actually December 31st, 2017 or is it January 8th, 2018?

Comment: Of course that is supported, http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Did you try anything before posting this question? If so, update your question with the results and clearly explain your issue. If not, then why not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-w"
df.string(from: Date())
```

> 2017-41

See e.g. http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns for the supported letters.